# Disabling the Maximize/Minimize trim space in Eclipse RCP 4

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin, e4

In Eclipse 3 and Eclipse 4, an `EditorSashContainer` looks like this when it has one `EditorStack`:

[image: EditorSashContainer with one EditorStack]

in Eclipse 4, it adds extra trim (which I've colored red) when there are multiple `EditorStacks`, which it didn't do in Eclipse 3:

[image: EditorSashContainer with multiple EditorStacks]

I understand that now that we're in E4, there's no such thing as `Editor`, `EditorStack`, and `EditorSashContainer` , just `Part`, `PartStack`, and `PartSashContainer`.  But there is something different between this "root" `PartSashContainer` and "regular" `PartSashContainer`, because only this "root" one has the maximize/minimize buttons and the extra trim:

[image: PartSashContainers with and without trim]

My question is this:

- What is different between "Root" and "Regular" `PartSashContainer` (maybe one isn't a `PartSashContainer`?)
- How do I disable this behavior?

My custom RCP application only has one "root" `PartSashContainer`, and it's unsettling for this extra trim to come and go.  I have mucked with `application.css`, and even gone as far as forking `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt`, but I'm stuck.

Comment: I don't think that is the PartSashContainer since it only appears when you split the editor area. It is probably something extra added by the split.

Comment: That was my first guess, but looking at the code, I can't find a suspect. https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/tree/master/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt/src/org/eclipse/e4/ui/workbench/addons/dndaddon

Comment: I believe it is an extra MArea added by MinMaxAddon but the code is extremely hard to read and even more difficult to change. If you install the Eclipse SDK you can read the Eclipse source in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Welp, it ain't pretty, but I found a way.  Thanks to greg-449 for the crucial `MArea` hint.

You can set the `rendererFactoryUri` by adding a snippet like this to your product extension:

```
<property
    name="rendererFactoryUri"
    value="bundleclass://com.myplugin/package.to.MyWorkbenchRendererFactory">
</property>
```

If you don't set it, Eclipse uses [this by default.](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/5420fb1b4fc1a364dee872c2f469c8712e2b5e5e/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt/src/org/eclipse/e4/ui/workbench/renderers/swt/WorkbenchRendererFactory.java)

If you set the renderer for `MArea` to be the regular `MPartSashContainer`'s renderer, it just works.

Here's my code:

```
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.MUIElement;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.MArea;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WorkbenchRendererFactory;

public class MyWorkbenchRendererFactory extends WorkbenchRendererFactory {
    private SashRenderer areaRenderer;

    @Override
    public AbstractPartRenderer getRenderer(MUIElement uiElement, Object parent) {
        if (uiElement instanceof MArea) {
            if (areaRenderer == null) {
                areaRenderer = new SashRenderer();
                initRenderer(areaRenderer);
            }
            return areaRenderer;
        } else {
            return super.getRenderer(uiElement, parent);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, now the "Minimize/Maximize" buttons will be rendered strangely, but I disable them anyway, so fixing that part is your problem ;-).